# What is the VB equivalent of this C# syntax, dealing with delegates?

Tags: c#, vb.net, delegates, lambda

Is it possible to translate the following C# code into VB.NET, using VB 9.0?

```
delegate Stream StreamOpenerDelegate(String name);

void Exec1()
{
    WorkMethod( x => File.OpenRead(x));
}

void Exec2()
{
    StreamOpenerDelegate opener = x => return File.OpenRead(x) ;
    WorkMethod(opener);
}
```

Can I do something like this?:

```
Private Delegate Function StreamOpenerDelegate(ByVal name As String) As Stream

Private Sub WorkMethod(ByVal d As StreamOpenerDelegate)
    ''
End Sub

Private Sub Exec1()
    Me.WorkMethod(Function (ByVal x As String) 
        Return File.OpenRead(x)
    End Function)
End Sub

Private Sub Exec2()
    Dim opener As StreamOpenerDelegate = Function (ByVal x As String) 
        Return File.OpenRead(x)
    End Function
    Me.WorkMethod(opener)
End Sub
```

I'm trying to write some documentation, but I don't know VB syntax.  Often I use [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/) to translate it, but I'm not sure it's working in this case.  I'm also not clear on where I would need line continuation characters.

---

**ANSWER**
In VB9, it's not possible to have multi-line lambdas (or Sub lambdas, which I did not ask about).  In VB9, all lambdas return a value, and must be a single expression. This changes in VB10.  VB10 will allow the above syntax, but VB9 will not.  In VB9, if the logic involves multiple code lines, it must not be a lambda; you must put it into a named Function and reference it explicitly.  Like this:

```
Private Delegate Function StreamOpenerDelegate(ByVal name As String) As Stream

Private Sub WorkMethod(ByVal d As StreamOpenerDelegate)
    ''
End Sub

Function MyStreamOpener(ByVal entryName As String) As Stream
    '' possibly multiple lines here
    Return File.OpenRead(entryName)
End Function

Private Sub Exec1()
    Me.WorkMethod(AddressOf MyStreamOpener)
End Sub
```

site: [Mike McIntyre's blog](http://cs.vbcity.com/blogs/mike-mcintyre/archive/2009/10/05/visual-basic-2010-multiline-sub-lambdas.aspx)

Comment: Well, I couldn't do more than asking Reflector here too. And it's quite good at translating syntaxes :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
Private Sub Exec1()
    Me.WorkMethod(Function (x) File.OpenRead(x))
End Sub

Private Sub Exec2()
    Dim opener As StreamOpenerDelegate = Function (x) File.OpenRead(x)

    Me.WorkMethod(opener)
End Sub
```

You need the line continuation character to split a single line statement into multiple lines, like so:

```
Private Sub Exec1()
    Me.WorkMethod(Function (x) _
                    File.OpenRead(x))
End Sub

Private Sub Exec2()
    Dim opener As StreamOpenerDelegate = Function (x) _
                                           File.OpenRead(x)

    Me.WorkMethod(opener)
End Sub
```

In any case, in [VS2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/865x40k4%28VS.100%29.aspx) there is implicit line continuation after certain characters. So I wouldn't worry about it too much.