# Hangfire and VB.NET - Gettings things configured in the Application Startup class

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, background-process, hangfire

Earlier this week I ran across Scott Hanselman's post about background processing in ASP.NET (http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToRunBackgroundTasksInASPNET.aspx). I've written routines in the past that automatically hits a page every so often to run some tasks, but this background processing idea is something I never even considered, and Hangfire (http://hangfire.io/) looks perfect for my background processing needs (mainly sending emails).

To get HangFire going (after installing it via NuGet) I need to get it started up in the Application Startup class. The documentation provides C# code that I'm not sure how to convert to VB.NET. It looks like some lambda code, which I'm somewhat familiar with through my use of LINQ, but I can't quick figure this one out.

```
public void Configure(IAppBuilder app)
{
    app.UseHangfire(config =>
    {
        config.UseSqlServerStorage("<connection string or its name>");
        config.UseServer();
    });
}
```

This is where I'm starting, which is basically next to nothing, I know... :)

```
Public Sub Configuration(app As IAppBuilder)
     'This is where I know this code should go... 
End Sub
```

I'd appreciate some direction or explanation as to what's going on here and how to port this code to VB.NET. Thanks!

Comment: I have a feeling this syntax will be similar to the concept in this post but am still not sure where to go with it... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1771184/what-is-the-vb-equivalent-of-this-c-sharp-syntax-dealing-with-delegates?rq=1

Comment: could you please point me towards startup/help/sample of Hangfire (.Net 4.0).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to write that as:

```
Public Sub Configure(app As IAppBuilder)
    Dim act = Sub(config As IBootstrapperConfiguration)
                config.UseSqlServerStorage("<...>")
                config.UseServer()
              End Sub

    app.UseHangfire(act)
End Sub
```

For more on creating multi line lambdas in VB.Net, refer to the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531298.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

I must be doing something wrong.  I too found Scott's blog post quite intriguing.  I too use VB and was having trouble.  The code @rfernandes shared was a welcome site.  However, I get an error at run time.

Here's my code:

```
Public Sub Configuration(app As IAppBuilder)
    Dim act = Sub(config As IBootstrapperConfiguration)
                  config.UseSqlServerStorage("HangfireDb")
                  config.UseServer()
              End Sub

    app.UseHangfire(act)
End Sub
```

The error occurs in the config.UseSqlServerStorage("HangfireDb") call.  An SqlException with the message "Column, parameter, or variable #5: Cannot find data type datetime2" is thrown.  I'm not sure what to do about this one.

*** After posting this non-answer I realized that I needed to post a separate question.  See [this Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26491255/hangfire-vb-startup-throws-sql-exception) for the rest of the story.